# ir.cron: "ERREUR: une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « model_id »

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

**I am trying to install a module in odoo 12 that contains a view with ir.cron module type. but it shows me this error:**
I do not know how to rectify it. Can anyone help me, please?

```
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "ERREUR:  une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « model_id »
DETAIL:  La ligne en échec contient (434, Annuler la remise mensuelle du client, ir.actions.server, null, null, action, 1, 2019-03-13 14:48:25.710923, 1, 2019-03-13 14:48:25.710923, ir_cron, object_write, 5, null, null, # Available variables:
#  - env: Odoo Environment on which the a..., null, null, null, null, null, null, null, days, specific, null, user_id)
" while parsing /home/*/PycharmProjects/Odoo12/*/sale_discount_total/views/cron.xml:5, near
<record model="ir.cron" id="deactivate_partner_discount_cron">
            <field name="name">Annuler la remise mensuelle du client</field>
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">months</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field eval="False" name="doall"/>
            <field eval="'res.partner'" name="model"/>
            <field eval="'deactivate_partner_discount'" name="function"/>
            <field eval="'()'" name="args"/>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the line `<field eval="'res.partner'" name="model"/>`, the actual field name is `model_id`. you have to set the field as following

```
<field name="model_id" ref="model_res_partner"/>
```

As `model_id` is a `Many2one` relation with `ir.model` you can use `ref` with model xml id, for `res.partner` model xml id is `model_res_partner`.

Answer (score 1):

> ERREUR:  une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « model_id »

Roughly translated, this error says:

> ERROR:  NULL value violates the NOT NULL constraint on the column `model_id`

If you look at the core code for an existing example of an `ir.cron` record, then you will see an XML node with the name `model_id`, which is required to create the cron record.

You are using:

```
<field eval="'res.partner'" name="model"/>
```

But in Odoo 12, this is expected instead:

```
<field name="model_id" ref="model_res_partner"/>
```

I haven't seen this in the Odoo Documentation anywhere, so I'll instead link to [some of the source code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8f4b98e67fe49516c0c830524de351db67c58357/addons/calendar/data/calendar_cron.xml#L7) so you can compare against your record.

Comment: Yes thank you a lot for your explanation! it works! I also wanted to ask you if you have a document that contains the different changes that have been made from odoo 10 to odoo 12.

Comment: @Omaima Unfortunately, I don't have anything comprehensive. The best resources that I have found are the migration notes maintained by the OCA. Here you can see [10.0 to 11.0 migration notes](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-11.0) and [11.0 to 12.0 migration notes](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-12.0), which contain a lot of good information, but you'll still need to do a good bit of review yourself. I suggest looking for examples in core code, especially if you can find the same piece from 10.0 and 12.0 to compare directly.

Comment: Thanks for your advices !! I will check the links you give me